# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class

Tags: java, scala, sbt, bing-api, bing-ads-api

I'm trying to download a report from BingAds. My code works inside IDEA downloading the report, no big issue. When I try to make it run inside sbt like:

H24_BING_CONFIG=/home/oleber/del/develop_bing.json sbt clean 'project importerBing' 'run'

The execution fails like:

```
[oleber] [WARN] [home24-aws] [org.apache.cxf.transport.https.HttpsURLConnectionFactory] [Default key managers cannot be initialized: /home/oleber/.keystore (No such file or directory)]
[oleber] [WARN] [home24-aws] [org.apache.cxf.transport.https.HttpsURLConnectionFactory] [Default key managers cannot be initialized: /home/oleber/.keystore (No such file or directory)]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:47)
    at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:194)
    at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:98)
    at javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:74)
    at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:146)
    at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:111)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJFactoryResolver.createMessageFactory(SAAJFactoryResolver.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor.getFactory(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:394)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invokeAsync(JaxWsClientProxy.java:297)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.submitGenerateReportAsync(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.bingads.reporting.ReportingServiceManager.submitDownloadAsync(ReportingServiceManager.java:196)
    at importer.bing.BingAdsImporterDownloader.submit(BingAdsImporterDownloader.scala:104)
    at importer.bing.BingAdsImporterDownloader$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BingAdsImporterDownloader.scala:171)
    at importer.bing.BingAdsImporterDownloader$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BingAdsImporterDownloader.scala:170)
    at common.ManagedResource$.withTmpDir(ManagedResource.scala:47)
    at importer.bing.BingAdsImporterDownloader$$anonfun$process$1.apply(BingAdsImporterDownloader.scala:170)
    at importer.bing.BingAdsImporterDownloader$$anonfun$process$1.apply(BingAdsImporterDownloader.scala:159)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:253)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:47)
    at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:194)
    at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:98)
    at javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:74)
    at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:146)
    at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:111)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJFactoryResolver.createMessageFactory(SAAJFactoryResolver.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor.getFactory(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:394)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invokeAsync(JaxWsClientProxy.java:297)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.submitGenerateReportAsync(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.bingads.reporting.ReportingServiceManager.submitDownloadAsync(ReportingServiceManager.java:196)
    at importer.bing.BingAdsImporterDownloader.submit(BingAdsImporterDownloader.scala:104)
    at importer.bing.BingAdsImporterDownloader$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BingAdsImporterDownloader.scala:171)
    at importer.bing.BingAdsImporterDownloader$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BingAdsImporterDownloader.scala:170)
    at common.ManagedResource$.withTmpDir(ManagedResource.scala:47)
    at importer.bing.BingAdsImporterDownloader$$anonfun$process$1.apply(BingAdsImporterDownloader.scala:170)
    at importer.bing.BingAdsImporterDownloader$$anonfun$process$1.apply(BingAdsImporterDownloader.scala:159)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:253)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

The warnings are in both places.

I'm completely lost. Do you have any possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

The warnings about the keystore are not relevant to the exceptions.

The problem is most probably that the failing build is lacking dependencies surrounding `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl`. IDEA probably delivers that dependency. This is possible since internal builds may live in another build environment (classpath/target platform).

The most common reasons for `NoClassDefFoundErrors` are exceptions thrown in static initializers of referenced classes (ExceptionInInitializer as root cause) and `ClassNotFoundExceptions` for referenced classes. The latter is what would happen if a dependency of the `SAAJMetaFactoryImpl` is missing, but not the library with the FactoryImpl itself.

I suspect the exception contains another `Caused-By` chain link which in turn contains the root cause of that exception, mentioning the actually missing class. Maybe you can reconfigure the build to display the complete cause-chain of thrown exceptions.

In general, try to compare the two build environments with respect to the target platforms they use to resolve dependencies. This makes the missing libraries obvious.